# ASP Alternating CSS Issue

Tags: asp.net, css

Currently I have 4 spans with alternating CSS tags.

```
<% var index =0 ; %>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.Take(4))  {
                    var css = (index%2==0)?"even":"odd";
    %>
        <span class="featured-products <%= css %>">
        <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= Html.Photo(PhotoExtensions.PhotoSizeType.HomepageThumb, item.DefaultPhoto)%></a>
        <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= item.ProductName%></a>
        </span>
    <%
    index ++ ;
    } %>
```

But I need for the last span to contain an extra CSS tag "last". Ive tried a couple of different methods but they all failed. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the :last-child CSS selector?  It may not be necessary to add additional markup if you can achieve what you want through CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much, had no idea that CSS property even existed till now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use CSS.

```
<% var index = 0; %>
<% var items = Model.Take(4); %>
<% foreach (var item in items)  {
                var css = (index%2==0)?"":"odd";
                if(index == items.Count - 1)
                {
                   css = " last";
                }
%>
    <span class="featured-products <%= css %>">
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= Html.Photo(PhotoExtensions.PhotoSizeType.HomepageThumb, item.DefaultPhoto)%></a>
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= item.ProductName%></a>
    </span>
<%
index ++ ;
} %>
```

Also, I would recommend cleaning this code up.  You don't need to put `<%` and `%>` everywhere.

**Update:** A bit cleaner way of writing what you're doing.  Definately not the cleanest but a good start.

```
<%
    var index = 0;
    var items = Model.Take(4);

    foreach (var item in items)  {
        var css = (index%2==0)?"":"odd";
        if(index == items.Count - 1)
        {
            css = " last";
        }

        %>
        <span class="featured-products <%= css %>">
        <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= Html.Photo(PhotoExtensions.PhotoSizeType.HomepageThumb, item.DefaultPhoto)%></a>
        <a href="<%= Url.Action("View", "Products", new {id = item.SKU}) %>"><%= item.ProductName%></a>
        </span>
        <%
        index ++ ;
    }
%>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner at .NET so every bit of code is a learning experience!

Comment: Looking at this again you can clean up your css classes. Discounting using CSS to do alternate styling, you don't need an "even" AND an "odd".  If this is a list of items, you should use an LI or UL tag instead of SPAN.

Comment: Ok, I'll throw together a cleaner version for you so you can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! Also I tried using your bit of code and I receive an error on this line 'if(index == items.Length - 1)'

Comment: Yeah, should be Count not Length

Comment: I added a little bit cleaner version of it so you can see what you like or dislike about it.